# controlling 3 input device by giving supply to either of the 2 pins

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, interfacing

I have a motor edge mirror(car mirror). It has 3 inputs. If I connect any 2 pins of these 3 pins to 12 volt (500 mA) power supply it rotates in one direction and so on.

I want to control that mirror with the help of voice commands.
e.g. if I say "forward" -the mirror will move forward. I am using [pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/). Up to the recognition part I have done successfully.

Next is , when I will say forward, the exact 2 pins, (those tend to move that mirror in forward direction) will get power supply and rest pin must be left open. 
Similarly,  when I will say backward, the exact 2 pins, (those tend to move that mirror in backward direction) will get power supply and rest pin must be left open.

Please suggest me how will be the circuit diagram to control that mirror.

Comment: This is not a software question and should be asked on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  That said, all you need is a [suitable relay board](http://www.modmypi.com/electronics/relays/8-channel-12v-relay-module/?gclid=Cj0KEQiA6vS2BRDH8dq06YDHz_IBEiQAzNdBmVQeQQucAonl1x3UAJ0JQbeDW6ZrgDB4Lcho2Okxlj8aAgKg8P8HAQ).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a software question.

Answer (score -1):

Although the question is not a software one. I can answer your question. Use Mosfets in between RPI and your Motors.
Typical block diagram

rpi ----->Mosfets------>motor

Example: take one pin of rpi (I/o) connect it to mosfet and from mosfet to motor pin.Like wise connect remaining two also to other pins. Now switch the Mosfets programmatically to operate motors.Ofcource you need to provide 12v and 500m power to each mosfet.Hope this helps

Comment: It is not a question for SO; if you nonetheless want to be helpful, you should provide advice as a comment.